# Is there an intuitive explanation as to why Galois Fields exist only for a prime powers?

Tags: abstract-algebra, information-theory

I am looking for an intuitive or example based explanation as to why Galois Fields exist only if the number of elements are a power of a prime. I find most explanations I've read difficult to understand. I am studying this topic from the perspective of Information Theory, and do not wish to delve too deep into the specifics.
Thank you.

Comment: A finite field is a vector space over $\Bbb F_p$, so has a basis $(x_1,\ldots ,x_n)$. But then counting gives, since every $x$ is a linear combination of the basis, that we have necessarily $p^n$ elements. So you only need to "delve deep into vector spaces", but this cannot be avoided anyway.

Comment: Do you know what the characteristic of a field is?