# Why must the order of a finite field be the power of a prime?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, prime-numbers, finite-fields

I've read the proof in my textbook, but it eventually boils down to contradiction, and in most cases the downside to proof by contradiction is that it removes some intuition. I also couldn't find any other explanation online! Can anyone give me an intuitive explanation as to why finite fields are of order $p^n$? I think this is a super cool fact, but I find it kind of hard to appreciate when I don't have the big picture in mind.

Comment: Usually it is used that the finite field is a vector space over the field of integers mod p.

Comment: I don't think you are correct in claiming it "boils down to a contradiction." Anyway... Duplicates: [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4328113/742), [two](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3674623/742), [three](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/132037/742), [four](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/72856/742).

Comment: Power residues form a group under multiplication is the closest my knowledge comes to this idea.